# Visual Studio Code not updating Python Interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I installed the `virtualenv` package for Visual Studio Code (VSC) and trying to install a certain version of Python into `myenv` folder that was created with the package. But after installing it, I go to change my Python Interpreter to Python 3.7.6 64-bit, which works by choosing it from the Command Palette. But when I open a Terminal from `myenv` and check the Python version, it still says Python 3.8.1.

I then went and added the alternative version path to my `Path` environment variables, restarted my computer, reopened VSC. But checking the version in Terminal still shows 3.8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? 3.8 is newer

Comment: I have to use an SDK that is not yet updated for 3.8.

Comment: K that's actually the reason I've not bothered to upgrade yet; I'll wait till 3.8 is widely supported.

Comment: you already activated myenv right

Comment: Hmm. So maybe I should uninstall 3.8 on my entire computer for now. But the whole point of a virtual environment is to use other versions. I wish I could get it to work. :(

Comment: Yeah, I was installing the 3.7 version and checking the version in Terminal from an activated VE.